# Google Earth Engine: Why image.convolve(laplacian) returns narrow lines instead of pixels?

Tags: google-earth-engine-javascript-api, edge-detection

I wanted to return pixels at edges using kernels like Laplacian (methods described here https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/image_convolutions).

```
// Define a Laplacian, or edge-detection kernel.
var laplacian = ee.Kernel.laplacian8({ normalize: false });

// Apply the edge-detection kernel.
var edgy = image.convolve(laplacian);
Map.addLayer(edgy,
             {bands: ['B5', 'B4', 'B3'], max: 0.5, format: 'png'},
             'edges');
```

However, I have noticed that the function convolve() returns a narrow line between the pixels of the original image (screenshot of an example below). Isn't it supposed to return pixels of the same size as the original image?

[image]

[image]

This narrow line is quite good for visualization, but I could not use it to return the pixels at the edges whatever the kernel used.
My problem: I could not return the pixels adjacent to edges to do further computations on them.